# Powershell result to Elasticlogsearch and Kibana dashboard

Tags: linux, windows, elasticsearch, kibana, metricbeat

I have installed kibana and elasticlogsearch (ELK) on linux and metricbeat on windows 2012. System logs of windows are getting shipped and displayed at Kibana dashboard.
I need to display get-hotfix result of powershell command to Kibana dashboard.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Update events are written to *System Log*-category of *Event Log*.

[image]

You need to use [winlogbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/winlogbeat/current/_winlogbeat_overview.html) to read required events from the event log and sent them to ES.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. But I want to display hotfix result on kibana dashboard in a graphical way.